# How to avoid the ExpressionChanged error, when using a method to set [ngClass]?

Tags: angular

I have the following components:

client-card.component.html:

```html
<div id="content">
<div id="card" (click)="viewDetails(client.clientId)">
  <div id="front">
    <div id="top-pic" [ngClass]="setTopPic()"></div>
    <div id="avatar"></div>
    <div id="info-box" [class.green]="(i + 1) % 2 == 0" [class.blue]="(i + 1) % 2 != 0">
      <div class="info">
        <h1>{{ client.surname }}, {{ client.forename }}</h1>
        <h2>{{ client.postcode }}</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

client-card.component.ts:

```ts
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-client-card',
  templateUrl: './client-card.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./client-card.component.css']
})
export class ClientCardComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() client: any = {};
  @Input() i: number;

  constructor(private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(`Init Card Component`)
  }

  viewDetails(clientId: number) {
    this.router.navigate(['/client', clientId]);
  }

  setTopPic() : string {
    if((this.i + 1) % 2 == 0) {
      return "blue" + Math.ceil(Math.random() * 4).toString();
    } else {
      return "green" + Math.ceil(Math.random() * 4).toString();
    }
  }

}
```

client-list.component.html:

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3" *ngFor="let client of clients; let i = index">
    <app-client-card [client]="client" [i]="i"></app-client-card>
  </div>
</div>
```

Whenever the client-list component displays the cards, I receive the following error in the console:

> ERROR Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'blue1'. Current value: 'blue2'.

I've read a few different explanations of various causes of this error, but am unfortunately no closer to resolving it.

Any assistance greatly appreciated.

Comment: as @rinukkusu explained, the problem is that the `setTopPic` function returns different values during checking and validation phases. It can be easily reproduced like this `let i = 0; setTopPic() { return i++ }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually you'll get this error while running in non-production mode and the cause is change detection running two times to check if you're not having a bug somewhere in your code which modifies data outside of the zone.

What's happening here is that your method `setTopPic()` might return a different value everytime it's called, so change detection is seeing `blue1` on checking the binding and `blue2` after that.

I'd suggest to store the class name in a member variable on init, since it relies on your other member variable `i`:

```ts
export class ClientCardComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() client: any = {};
  @Input() i: number;

  topPic: string;

  constructor(private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(`Init Card Component`);
    this.topPic = setTopPic(); // <-- here
  }
```

And use that in the binding:

```html
<div id="top-pic" [ngClass]="topPic"></div>
```

Comment: That's cracked it!

Comment: Hey, I just revised my answer, since I realized, the `setTopPic` method relies on the `i` member variable - please check it out! :)

Comment: _to check if you're not having a bug somewhere in your code which modifies data outside of the zone_ - that's not exactly this purpose of the check, read [Everything you need to know about the `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError` error](https://blog.angularindepth.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-expressionchangedafterithasbeencheckederror-error-e3fd9ce7dbb4)